# Hide the "ask your own question" message at the bottom of your own questions

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

At the bottom of a question page there's this text:

> Not the answer you're looking for?
>   Browse other questions tagged [tags]
>   or ask your own question.

Shouldn't the "ask your own question" part should be omitted if it is already "your own question"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like after you have already answered a question and the bottom note says 'Add Another Answer,'  perhaps it should say something like 'Ask another question.'